# Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class debug error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have the following piece of code that tries to insert a document object into mongoDB.

```
        return reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(document)
                .doOnSuccess(filler -> System.out.println(filler))
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    String message = format("Error saving %s", e.getMessage());
                    log.error(message, e);
                    throw new PersistenceException(message, e);
                })
                .block();
```

When I debug I get an error that says org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class org.bson.Document!

This is identified to be in the first line with the return. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug (at least it is similar to [this reported issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2374)).
Anyway, it seems [the *insert* method that includes the collection name as the second parameter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoTemplate.html#insert-T-java.lang.String-) does work correctly:

```
return reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(document, "documentCollection")
  // ...
```

That worked for me.

Comment: confirmed, can't believe this is still a problem in 2022